# Different proofs to show that $\mathrm{C}[a, b]$ is not finite dimensional.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $[a, b]$ be any closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive length. Let us define
$$
\mathrm{C}[a, b]:=\{f \mid f:[a, b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \text { continuous }\}
$$
Prove that $\mathrm{C}[a, b]$ is not finite dimensional.

**A proof.** Let
$$
p(t):=a_n t^n+\cdots+a_1 t+a_0
$$
be a finite linear combination of monomials, where $a_0, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$. We suppose that not all coefficients $a_j$ are zero, and we have to show that then $p$ cannot be the zero function.

If $p(c)=0$, then there exists a polynomial $q$ such that $p(t)=(t-c) q(t)$ and $\operatorname{deg} q<\operatorname{deg} p$. If we apply this procedure repeatedly, we can write
$$
p(t)=\left(t-c_1\right)\left(t-c_2\right) \ldots\left(t-c_k\right) q(t)
$$
for some $k \leq n$ and some polynomial $q$ that has no zeroes in $[a, b]$. But that means that $p$ can have only finitely many zeroes in $[a, b]$. Since the interval $[a, b]$ has infinitely many points, we are done. **[See "Functional Analysis An Elementary Introduction" by Markus Haase]**

My question is, do you know of any other ways to prove this statement?

Comment: The space $\mathcal{C}\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ is infinite dimensional because the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$ is linearly independent - see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599827/proof-that-vector-space-ca-b-of-all-functions-from-a-b-to-mathbbr-i).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: this is the OP’s proof, and they’re specifically asking for other proofs (which aren’t in the thread that you link), so are you sure it’s a dupe?

Comment: @Aphelli Just considering the span of the monomials seems to be much more concise than what the OP wrote, and therefore different. The other post has several answers. More or less every reasonable answer is this way, I believe.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: what makes the OP’s proof longer is that they show that a nonzero polynomial must have finitely many roots. In the post that you link, there’s only one answer specifically mentioning $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ and this is the proof it gives, so it doesn’t give another proof…

Comment: No, also the answer by José Carlos Santos is also specifically mentioning $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$. I still think saying that "it doesn't give another proof" is a bit opinion-based, and I am not sure whether or not there is any proof which we could not compare to the standard one. But I didn't close the question, so ...

Comment: There's also a construction involving sine waves of different frequencies - which you can arrange to be pairwise orthogonal, and therefore independent. I think both of these are actually a bit "cleverer" than they need to be, because of the following: you can construct a family of functions $f_n: [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ with $f_n(1/n) = 1$ and $f_n(1/m) = 0$ for $m \ne n$. (This isn't hard - in fact just take the constraints given and fill in the gaps "piecewise-linearly"). You can even do this with smooth functions! These are then clearly linearly independent.